# Найти текстовые файлы в папке

Tags: java

Постановка задачи.
Есть папка с файлами, надо перебрать файлы и проверить, какие из них текстовые.

Как осуществить саму проверку?
Как проверить, текстовый это файл или нет?

В результате все текстовые файлы будут сравниваться по содержимому.

Comment: а вот если к вопросу добавить "упущеную" метку учебное-задание, тогда все встанет на свои места. и можно будет не поленится вбить нное количество расширений файлов (хотя в принцыпе хватит и 2х перечисленных @shurik)

Comment: Говоря что файл текстовый я имею ввиду что в файле есть текст, смысловой, а не произвольные символы.

Файл может не иметь расширения вообще, может иметь произвольное расширение.

Comment: Т.е. не любой текст, а обязательно имеющий смысл? Но вы ведь понимаете, что в общем случае задача в такой формулировке не имеет решения.

Comment: :~$ which file
/usr/bin/file

:~$ file /usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

:~$ file /var/log/boot.log
/var/log/boot.log: ASCII Pascal program text, with CRLF, CR line terminators, with escape sequences

Comment: Переписать file на Java ? Хорошее учебное задание (на курсовик потянет ?)

Answer (score 1):

Есть [целая куча способов](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html). Многие из них основаны на чтении первых 512 байтов. Однако, это наверное, не самый быстрый способ. Уверен, что для действительно большого дерева файлов это будет работать много часов.

Comment: Да, Java небыстра, но настолько ? (много часов). Недавно пришлось искать grep -R в дереве мегабайт на 100. Минут 15.

Comment: Ну так что такое 100 мегабайт? Я бы сказал, что это как-то медленновато для grep'а. Кроме того, простой поиск это одно, а определение типа сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить что по перечисленным расширениям. Типа .txt, .log ...

Ну а другой метод - читаем файл и смотрим - есть ли там не текстовые символы.. такие как \x00, \x01, \x02 ...

Comment: перечислить все типы - не реально

могут быть разные языки
тогда этот метод не подойдет.